# PHP function add datetime stamp when tick box on form is ticked

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation

I have a form that is running in Ninja Forms and there is a custom bit of code that fires the details to an external API, the issue i'm having is two-fold.

I need to make it so that if you tick the gdpr_consent_date tick box it fires a datetime (js timetstamp) to the API through this process, and then if you tick the email_uptdate_optin a boolean whether its been checked or not.

Here is the code being used:

```
function signup_form_process() {
global $ninja_forms_processing;

if ($ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID() !== 7) {
return;
}

$url = 'https://' . APP_DOMAIN . '/account/alternative_signup';

$data = get_sign_up_form_data([
'email' => 11,
'name' => 12,
'password' => 13,
'time_zone_offset' => 26,
'gdpr_consent_date'=> 132,
'email_update_optin'=> 133,
]);

$old_account = login_old_api($data['email'], $data['password']);
$old_status_code = substr($old_account['response'], 0, 3);
$old_message = substr($old_account['response'], 
strpos($old_account['response'], '~') + 1);

if ($old_status_code === '200' || $old_status_code === '401' || 
$old_status_code === '409') {
$ninja_forms_processing->add_error('error_old_account', sprintf(__('The account %s already exists, <a href="%s" class="alert-link">please login here.</a>', 'sage'), $data['email'], home_url('/login/')));
return;
}

$options = [
'http' => [
  'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
              "Accept: application/json",
  'method'  => 'POST',
  'content' => json_encode($data),
  'ignore_errors' => true
],
];

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
$headers = Utils\parse_headers($http_response_header);

Utils\log('Signup API Response:');
Utils\log(['response' => $result, 'headers' => $headers]);

if (strpos($headers['status'], '201') === 0) {
$data['username'] = $data['email'];
$data['remember_me'] = 0;
unset($data['email']);
unset($data['name']);
post_login($data);
} else {
if (is_array($result->error)) {
  $ninja_forms_processing->add_error('error_api', $result->error[1]);
} else if (!empty($result->error)) {
  $ninja_forms_processing->add_error('error_api', $result->error);
} else {
  $ninja_forms_processing->add_error('error_api', __('An unknown error occurred.', 'sage'));
}
}
}
add_action('ninja_forms_post_process', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\signup_form_process');
```

I'm a bit stuck, if someone could help that would be awesome!

Chris

Comment: thats not enough code to help

Comment: Have updated to the full code used in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of the input for gdpr_consent_date to `<?php date('H:i:s d-m-Y') ?>` and simply `true` for the checkbox.

Date formatting can be changed to your needs, more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: slight issue.. Ninja forms doesn't allow me to change the value of the gdpr_consent_date to <?php date('H:i:s d-m-Y') ?> they are a bit set as being either checked or unchecked.

Comment: Sorry, never used Ninja forms. Perhaps you could check if gdpr_consent_date is `true` and then set it to date? Something along the lines of: `if( gdpr_consent_date ) { gdpr_consent_date = date(); }`